# MKStoreManager hangs on buyFeature with error: Thread 1, EXC: BAD ACCESS

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting, mkstorekit

Project quit with error: Thread 1, EXC: BAD ACCESS.

```
[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:kFeatureAId 
onComplete:^(NSString* purchasedFeature) 
{ NSLog(@"Purchased: %@", purchasedFeature); } 
onCancelled:^ { NSLog(@"User Cancelled Transaction"); }];
```

I use ARC in my project, so I set **-fno-objc-arc** flag for JSONKit and SFHFKeychainUtils.

Comment: I have a same issue, it crushes when I hit this method on Xcode4.2. It worked fine on the previous Xcode though.

Comment: I used sample from http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases instead. It works